# The ways that web server can know who you are and what browser you use

Tags: http, web-scraping, http-headers

I am speaking about basic HTTP GET request. As far as know the browser sends request header within HTTP request (which includes cookies, user-agents, etc.). The server also is able to see the originating IP address, request URL, request method. What other info can they use in order to get info on users hardware, software and other properties?

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint and https://panopticlick.eff.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are 4 pretty standard user-agent headers. I used an online user-agent parser tool like [this one](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/parse/) to get the OS and browser. If you try the tool yourself you'll see a lot more information is available from these user-agent headers.

Note, it is always possible for someone to spoof a user-agent header. For example, if they're sending requests using a Python script, they can change the default user-agent to any of the below.

Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Safari on Darwin:

```
Safari/13604.1.38.1.6 CFNetwork/887 Darwin/17.0.0 (x86_64)
```

Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
```

Edge 38 on Windows 10:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393
```